# Account re-registration in pjsip

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm using pjsip in my application. At the time of registration I set the timeout to 60 sec. After every 60 seconds my account will re-register but in my case it is not happening. If anybody knows why, please tell me (I set whatever fields required to call pjsip account add method, if i miss any thing please tell me).

```
setRegistration(String sipUser, String password,String sipServer) {

    int status = pjsuaConstants.PJ_FALSE;
    /* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */
    {

        int[] accId = new int[1];

        accId[0] = 1;

        pjsua_acc_config cfg = new pjsua_acc_config();
        pjsua.acc_config_default(cfg);
        csipsimple_acc_config css_cfg = new csipsimple_acc_config();
        pjsua.csipsimple_acc_config_default(css_cfg);
        cfg.setPriority(100);
        cfg.setId(pjsua.pj_str_copy("sip:" + sipUser + "@" + sipServer));
        cfg.setReg_uri(pjsua.pj_str_copy("sip:" + sipServer
                + ";transport=udp;lr")); 
        cfg.setReg_timeout(60);
        cfg.setCred_count(1);

        cfg.setPublish_enabled(0);
        cfg.setReg_delay_before_refresh(-1);

        cfg.setUse_timer(pjsua_sip_timer_use.PJSUA_SIP_TIMER_OPTIONAL);

        pjsip_cred_info cred_info = cfg.getCred_info();
        cred_info.setRealm(pjsua.pj_str_copy(sipServer));
        cred_info.setScheme(pjsua.pj_str_copy("Digest"));
        cred_info.setUsername(pjsua.pj_str_copy(sipUser));
        cred_info
                .setData_type(pjsip_cred_data_type.PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD
                        .swigValue());
        cred_info.setData(pjsua.pj_str_copy(password));
        cfg.setKa_interval(0);

        pjsua.csipsimple_set_acc_user_data(cfg, css_cfg);
        Log.i("status", "acc is adding....");
        status = pjsua.acc_add(cfg, pjsuaConstants.PJ_FALSE, accId);
        Log.i("status", "acc is added");

        if (status == pjsuaConstants.PJ_SUCCESS) {
            status = pjsua.acc_set_online_status(accId[0], 1);
            Log.i("Setting online status to online", "---online--" + status);
        } else {
            Log.i("Not success", "---un success--" + status);
        }
    }
    return status == pjsuaConstants.PJ_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Logs

```
05-03 12:17:58.820: I/libpjsip(1003): 12:17:58.826    pjsua_acc.c
```

registration success, status=200 (OK), will re-register in 60 seconds

```
05-03 12:17:58.820: D/libpjsip(1003): 12:17:58.827    pjsua_acc.c  ....Keep-alive timer started for acc 1, destination:4.53.123.201:5060, interval:40s
```

Comment: Post the relevant piece of your code. No one can help you without that. Also, add logs around the important pieces of code and show what you are getting (which logs are hit).

Comment: did you manage to make it working?

Comment: in the above code re-registeration is not happening ,why?

Comment: in the above code registeration is working properly but after timeout sipserver not re-registering the account,that is problem if anybody knows tell me.

Comment: according to pjsip documentation this timer will active if registration failed in first place.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483996/error-while-trying-registering-with-pjsip-pjsip-eunsuptransport/16518017#16518017)

I don't know the problem you were facing but when I tried to use your code I had a problem and I managed to fix it as described in the related question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the interval

> cfg.reg_retry_interval

I am pretty sure that Java API provides this property.