# Error while trying registering with pjsip: PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT

Tags: android, pjsip, csip-simple

I'm developing a SIP client based on pjsip on Android (i'm using the csipsimple code as a reference for now).

WHen I try to register the account I get the following error:

> Unable to generate suitable Contact header for registration:
>   Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)

My code is almost the same as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353653/account-re-registration-in-pjsip)
The sipServer string is the ip address of the registrar "192.168...."

I have also tried not to specify the transport method like in the following code:

```
        int[] accId = new int[1];

        accId[0] = 1;

        pjsua_acc_config cfg = new pjsua_acc_config();
        pjsua.acc_config_default(cfg);
        csipsimple_acc_config css_cfg = new csipsimple_acc_config();
        pjsua.csipsimple_acc_config_default(css_cfg);
        cfg.setPriority(10);
        cfg.setId(pjsua.pj_str_copy("sip:" + sipUser + "@" + sipServer));
        cfg.setReg_uri(pjsua.pj_str_copy("sip:" + sipServer)); 
        cfg.setReg_timeout(60);
        cfg.setCred_count(1);

        cfg.setPublish_enabled(0);
        cfg.setReg_delay_before_refresh(-1);

        cfg.setUse_timer(pjsua_sip_timer_use.PJSUA_SIP_TIMER_OPTIONAL);
        pjsua.csipsimple_set_acc_user_data(cfg, css_cfg);
        status = pjsua.acc_add(cfg, pjsuaConstants.PJ_FALSE, accId);
```

The error is:

> E/libpjsip(20934): pjsua_acc.c 
>   ..Unable to generate suitable Contact header for registration:
>   Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT) [status=171060]

Of course after this there is no trace on wireshark: the lib gives up before sending any data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following code:

```
    int[] tId = new int[1];
    int status;
    pjsua.transport_config_default(cfgTrasport);
    cfgTrasport.setPort(5060);
    status = pjsua.transport_create(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, cfgTrasport, tId);
    if (status != pjsuaConstants.PJ_SUCCESS) {
        Log.e("pjsua.transport_create returned status="+status);
    }
```